# NFC app based on Titanium works only if NFC code is in index.js

Tags: javascript, android, nfc, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a problem with Appcelerator Titanium's `ti.nfc module`.

It works well only if the NFC code is in index.js, if I pass from index.js to another page like login.js with this code:

```
var login = Alloy.createController("login").getView();
login.open();
```

and I put the same NFC code from index.js to login.js it doesn't work.

This is the code that works:

**index.js**

```
var nfc = require('ti.nfc');
var nfcAdapter = null;
// Create the NFC adapter to be associated with this activity. 
// There should only be ONE adapter created per activity.
nfcAdapter = nfc.createNfcAdapter({
    onNdefDiscovered: handleNDEFDiscovery,
    onTagDiscovered: handleTAGDiscovery,
    onTechDiscovered: handleTECHDiscovery
});

function handleNDEFDiscovery(data){
    //Ti.API.info('NDEF DISCOVERED:: ' + data.messages[0].records[0].getPayload());
    // Our required payload fits in the first record of the first Ndef msg
    var payload = data.messages[0].records[0].getPayload();
    // First byte of payload is control byte
    // Bits 5 to 0 of the control bytes contain 
    // length of language code succeeding the control byte
    var langCodeLength = payload[0] & 0077;
    // Received NFC text data starts after textOffset bytes in payload
    var textOffset = langCodeLength + 1;
    // Payload contains byte array which needs to be converted to a string
    // nfc_text contains the exact text string sent by the sending NFC device
    var nfc_text = payload.toString().substring(textOffset);
    /* process nfc_text as required by application logic here */
}

function handleTAGDiscovery(data){
    //Ti.API.info('TAG DISCOVERED:: ' + data.messages[0].records[0].getPayload());
}

function handleTECHDiscovery(data){
    //Ti.API.info('TECH DISCOVERED:: ' + data.messages[0].records[0].getPayload());
    var tag = data.tag;
    alert('Tag ID: ' + tag.getId());
}

// Check for NFC support on device
if (!nfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Ti.API.info('NFC is not enabled on this device!');
}else{        
    // Tag scans are received by the current activity as new intents. We
    // need to pass scan intents to the nfc adapter for processing.
    var act = Ti.Android.currentActivity;
    act.addEventListener('newintent', function(e) {
        nfcAdapter.onNewIntent(e.intent);
    });
    // Since we want the app to only use NFC while active in the foreground
    // We disable and enable foreground dispatch on app pause and resume respectively
    act.addEventListener('resume', function(e) {
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(dispatchFilter);
    });
    act.addEventListener('pause', function(e) {
        nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch();
    });

    // The foreground dispatch filter specifies the types of NFC 
    // messages the app wants to receive and handle. The only entry in our case
    // specifies type ‘text/plain’ since we want to send and receive plain text     
    dispatchFilter = nfc.createNfcForegroundDispatchFilter({
        intentFilters: [
            { action: nfc.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED },
        ],
        techLists: [
            [ "android.nfc.tech.NfcV" ]
        ]
    });
    // This enables foreground dispatch for the first time
    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(dispatchFilter);
}
```

**Android tiapp.xml:**

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <manifest>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
                <application>
                    <activity
                     android:label="TagViewer" android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium"
                     android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
                     android:launchMode="singleTask">
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                        </intent-filter>
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                            <data android:scheme="http"/>
                        </intent-filter>
                    </activity>
                </application>
            </manifest>
        </android>
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error?

Comment: When I hold a tag-card against the back of the phone, I don't receive the tag discovery event in my onTechDiscovered callback.

Answer (score 0):

This might well be an issue with using `Ti.Android.currentActivity`. Try to use [Ti.Window.activity](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-activity) instead, with the window being the Window (or TabGroup) for the login view.

If this solves it, then it looks like we have a bug in `Ti.Android.currentActivity` and/or the docs need updating.

Comment: I tried to replace Ti.Android.currentActivity with Ti.Window.activity, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Then could yoy check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/)? If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.